# d3.js Highlight Nodes/Paths - Connected Nodes Won't Highlight

Tags: javascript, d3.js

To highlight a node and the connected nodes/paths on click, I am following this example: http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/

I inserted this code:

```
  //---Insert-------

  //Toggle stores whether the highlighting is on
  var toggle = 0;

  //Create an array logging what is connected to what
  var linkedByIndex = {};
  for (i = 0; i < data.nodes.length; i++) {
      linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
  };
  data.links.forEach(function (d) {
      linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
  });

  //This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
  function neighboring(a, b) {
      return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
  }

  function connectedNodes() {

      if (toggle == 0) {
          //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
          d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
          circle.style("opacity", function (o) {
              return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
          });

          path.style("opacity", function (o) {
              return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
          });

          //Reduce the op

          toggle = 1;
      } else {
          //Put them back to opacity=1
          circle.style("opacity", 1);
          path.style("opacity", 1);
          toggle = 0;
      }

  }
```

I added this line to the nodes:

```
.on('click', connectedNodes)
```

The result is that when a node is clicked, it's connected paths are highlighted correctly, but the node and its connected nodes are not highlighted. Instead, all nodes are reduced to the 0.1 opacity. How would I alter the code to properly highlight the connected nodes?

Comment: I'm not seeing the same behavior. I edited the fiddle so that .on('dblclick', was changed to .on('click', and it worked as expected. Can you provide a link to your specific non-working code?

Comment: I haven't worked with jfiddle before, but I will attempt to put together some data and get an example up. I figured it might just be something easy I am missing because all I did was change `.on('dblclick'` to `.on('click'`, `node` to `circle`, and `link` to `path`. I'm thinking it should be something in the first part of the `connectedNodes` function.